# Android app for finding a friend

Tags: android, eclipse

How can I find friends within 5 meters by using google maps?

Presently I am using google maps api location manager class to locate the user, but how can I find the number of friends nearby and locate them on the map along with the user?

Comment: Stop staring at your phone, have a look around, if your friends are within 5 metres, you should be able to see them.

Answer (score 0):

If all your friends are using your app you can have your app uploading locations to server (automatically), and then let server calculate distances, returning you locations of friends nearby (then you can draw it to map) and their count.

You would have to think about data/energy consumption vs precision, so I'm not sure it's good solution.

Comment: but without using server how can i make use of location manager class to locate friends around?

Comment: Thanks KaderkM. I'll make use of server and I am working on finding the best solution for mapping friends from that database.